# PDE and Linear operators

Tags: partial-differential-equations, operator-theory

Consider a linear PDE which can be seen as 
L[u] = 0, where L is a linear differential operator on u.
Is there any theory that tries to study the PDE by sutdying the kernel of L?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This is the functional-analytic formulation of the study of linear PDEs, in which a linear differential operator $L$ is viewed as a linear operator between two appropriate vector spaces. For example, $L$ is a differential operator of order $k$ and $u$ is assumed to live on some domain $U$, then one might naturally think of considering $L$ as an operator from $C^k(U)\to C(U)$. ($C^k(U)$ denotes the space of $k$-times continuously differentiable functions on $U$, $C(U)$ the space of continuous functions on $U$.) A solution $u$ to the linear PDE $Lu = 0$ can then be thought of as an element of $\ker L \subset C^k(U)$.

Unfortunately, this formulation of the problem with the spaces $C^k(U)$ and $C(U)$ can be very difficult to deal with. But the reason this approach works well is that we actually have a lot of leeway in choosing our vector spaces. This leads one to the notion of [weak solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_solution/) and vector spaces such as [Sobolev space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space/) and [spaces of distributions, AKA generalized functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_%28mathematics%29/). Typically finding weak solutions, then converting weak solutions to classical (i.e. continuously differentiable, or similarly regular) solutions is easier than searching for a classical solution from the get-go.

This is a main approach in modern PDE, and is also applicable to differential operators that are not quite linear. It has much interplay with the study of the variational formulation of a PDE and with Fourier analysis.